# Installed Wordpress Network with www in the Site URL. How do I fix this?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I made a huge mistake. I set up a network without changing sitename to non-www, so now example.com (without www) is a non-existing page. How do I fix this? Changes in

- settings
- DNS
- htaccess
  ?

I've tried htaccess redirect but wordpress sees the first request and still says www is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't edit the Wordpress source code to redirect, as it will be broken on future updates. We can't forward all requests to the www-version of that request as that will break all subdomains.

I solved this with some edits to the root .htaccess file.

```
# This is probably how your file starts already
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Then you add a condition: if the host starts with example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com.*$
# And add a rule: redirect that url to the same url just with prepended with www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Here the file continues with other stuff from WP
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```